# ColorFilter Add but ignore transparent parts

Tags: android, porter-duff

In my app I am trying to change the color of my marker image. But it doesn't work exactly how I want it to work.

```
Drawable drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_marker);
drawable.setColorFilter(item.getColor()), PorterDuff.Mode.ADD);
```

The drawable looks like this (below), when I add the ColorFilter the marker gets the correct color and the white stays white, but also the transparent part of the image gets the color. I only want the black to change and the white and transparent part have to stay that way.

[image: drawable]

Comment: try multiply, instead of add, or `ColorMatrixColorFilter` to make some other fancy stuff

Comment: That way the black stays black and the white gets a new color. Transparent is still transparent tho.

Comment: so give `ColorMatrixColorFilter` a try

Comment: Any tips how? I have never worked with ColorMatrixColorFilter before. I have change the marker to different RGB codes.

Comment: ok then, why dont you use a `LayerDrawable`? with `LayerDrawable` you can colorify any layer you want

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for experiments with [setColorFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter), [ColorMatrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix)   and [ColorMatrixColorFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrixColorFilter):

```
drawable.setColorFilter(item.getColorMatrix());
```

**OR**:

```
drawable.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(getColorMatrix5()));//custom 5

//custom 5
private ColorMatrix getColorMatrix5() 
{
    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);//make it greyscale
    ColorMatrix blueMatrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[] {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // red
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // green
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, // blue
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1  // alpha
    });
    // Convert, then scale and clamp
    colorMatrix.postConcat(blueMatrix);
    return colorMatrix;
}//getColorMatrix5
```

See [PorterDuff](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff), [`PorterDuff.Mode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode),[`PorterDuffXfermode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuffXfermode), [`ColorFilter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter),[ColorMatrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix),  [ColorMatrixColorFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrixColorFilter),  [PorterDuffColorFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuffColorFilter), [`Canvas`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawcolor), [`Color`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color).